# Using RestKit with local server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios, restkit

I've got RestKit in my iPhone app interacting with a Rails app on Heroku, but RestKit won't seem to work with the Rails app running locally on my machine. Here's the output in my iPhone app:

`Fail: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/1.json, NSUnderlyingError=0x2a9690 "Could not connect to the server."}`

I've done all the sanity checks. `http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/1.json` returns a JSON object in my browser and when I change the root URL to the app on Heroku, RestKit works fine.

Is there something I'm missing? How do I get RestKit to work with the local version of my app?

Comment: Are you running the iPhone app from the simulator or the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a dumb error on my part. An app running on a device obviously can't access a rails app running on localhost.

This works fine in the simulator or when pointed to a production server.

Comment: Totally just got bit by this too. If only my lightning connector could do THAT.